# Amazon Payments in OpenCart - missing order details in back-office

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, payment-gateway, amazon-pay

I have just set up Amazon Payments as a payment method at my store, but have an important issue with it. I can successfully go through the payment process, i.e. I've done a couple of test orders and received order confirmation e-mails accordingly, but when I go into the back-office (Dashboard), I do not see any Payment and Shipping Details :

[image: Missing order details]

For what it's worth, I've only done test orders in Sandbox mode.

Is that an issue with Amazon Payments and what would be its solution, or is this the 'proper' way that Amazon Payments works, i.e. it has not been designed to return order information details back to OpenCart?

Comment: This is strange and I am almost sure something else is going on there. The order is saved before the payment method is invoked... Therefore You should be able to see the data.

Comment: I've just installed a default & clean OpenCart 1.5.6 specifically to test Amazon Payments - again, the order details simply do not show at all. I'm starting to wonder if that's a bug with the extension or  coded this way for a reason...

Comment: It could be a bug. Support for 1.5.x is limited. OpenCart >= 2.0.1 have Pay with Amazon built-in by default.